# Font showing glyph boundary over text

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, glyph

I'm showing a clock on my webpage. The font I'm using is called [DSEG](https://www.keshikan.net/fonts-e.html). I'm noticing a problem where a very thin horizontal line appears above the 1 and the 4. This seems like it's boxing the character. It looks like this only happens in Chrome.

[image: 06:32:41]

I can't tell if it's coming from the font or if there is some CSS trick that will remove it. My CSS is very simple:

HTML:

```
<div class="clock>{time}</div>
```

where time is dynamic text generated via javascript (changes every second)

CSS:

```
.clock {
  font-family: 'DSEG7 Classic';
  font-size: 8rem;
  margin-top: 1rem};
}
```

[Here's a glitch demo](https://lyrical-fierce-eclipse.glitch.me/)

For the font-face, I have a base64 encoding of the woff2 and I'm doing a regular url of the woff file.
Has anyone seen this kind of issue? Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Read this very carefully, make a demo of the issue on the pic...

Comment: Sure, updated my post with a demo

Comment: Looks ok in FF.

Comment: yes, I think this only happens in Chrome